# Error when converting string numbers to float in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

While reading in a csv file (kidney_disease.csv from https://www.kaggle.com/mansoordaku/ckdisease/data), pandas mistakenly assigns the columns **pcv**, **wc** and **rc** the dtype object (should be float). 
Specifying the dtypes leads to the an error:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["pcv", "wc", "rc"], 
                   dtype={"pcv": np.float64, "wc": np.float64, "rc": np.float64})

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\t?'
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? All values in these columns are either strings which correspond to numbers or nan.
And is there a possibilty for pandas to "guess" the dtype based on the first 100 rows or something like this?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source data file is not clean. You should read in the file first and then parse to float.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('kidney_disease.csv')
cols = ['pcv','wc','rc']
df = df[cols]
for col in cols:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col],downcast='float',errors='coerce')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output

```
pcv    float32
wc     float32
rc     float32
dtype: object
```

This will result in `nan` values where strings could not be converted. You should examine your dataset to see what other cleaning may be required.

Comment: This works, thank you very much. The problem was, that for some reason in a certain row a *?* was placed instead of a *nan*...

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom conversion function:

```
def str_to_float(x):
    return float(x.strip())

data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=["pcv", "wc", "rc"], 
                   dtype={"pcv": np.float64, "wc": np.float64, "rc": np.float64},
                   converters={"pcv": str_to_float, "wc": str_to_float, "rc": str_to_float})
```

Comment: @nhaus Try adding a `print(x)` before the `return` and re-run the code. What output does it give?